# Django model tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, tags, django-admin

I am working on a django app and need to add a tags field to one of my models.
In the admin interface i need it to work like the wordpress tagging.. (comma separated entry, auto create new tags and autcomplete)

There are two tagging libraries I found, `django-tagging` and `django-taggit`, both also have an autcomplete extension.

The problem is that both of them are very old (last update was 2 years ago), unmaintained and needs some work to bring them up to speed.

Is there any good, recent tagging module i didn't find?

Comment: I use django-tagging and still works like a Charm, what are the issues you found with it?

Answer (score 0):

Both are good. I have used Django-tagging in over 30 projects, and am yet to find an issue. Is there a specific challenge